# Cannot replace &amp; with & in JSON textResponse

Tags: javascript, json, titanium-mobile

I've written a PHP-script that parses a list from remote website and output the result as JSON form my iPhone app which is built on Titanium Mobile.

This is my header: `header('content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');`
Also tried with ISO-8859-1 but problem persists.

I print the textResponse in the titanium console and see that the &-characters are represented as `&amp;`. Same result when I make the same request in my web browser.

I try to replace `&amp;` with & using replace('`&amp;`', '&') but it has no effect, `&amp;` is still `&amp;`.

```
var events = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Titanium.API.info(events);

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var id = events[i].id;
        var title = events[i].title;

        var amp = title.search('&amp;');
        if (amp != -1) {
            title.replace('&amp;', '&');
            Titanium.API.info(amp);
            Titanium.API.info(title);
        }

        var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({title: title, id: id, hasChild: true});
        rowData[i] = row;           
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
title = title.replace('&amp;', '&');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post your php script as reference. You may want to make sure you are decoding the URLs prior to printing them to the JSON.